# Flex-basis can't control overflows?

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

It seems like flex-basis can't overrule overflowing children, such as when white-space: nowrap is in effect. In the example below, if I remove white-space: nowrap, flex-basis works as intended. The only way to force the width to be 80px is to use max-width. Is this the correct way to achieve this behavior?

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="text">
    Overflow Me
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.parent {
  background: beige;
  display: flex;

  .button {
    flex: 0 1 80px;
    display: flex;

    .text {
        background: lightblue;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }  
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pjfyqfa7/8/

Comment: Just saw the max-width part, so what is the nested flexbox for?

Comment: @Stickers Sorry, the `display: flex` inside of the .button class does nothing in this example, it was a mistake.

Comment: Flex-basis is **not the same** as width.